# tensorflow gpu usage without compat.v1

Tags: python

Can someone help me on this?

what is the code syntax of using gpu in tensorflow 2.2.0 without using the compat.v1?

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3)# i used this with compat.v1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure a logicl GPU device.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

I recommend you reading this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth